# SqlAlchemy Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm trying to update two database records in the same function, but I'm always getting this error here:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Unconsumed column names: skills, github_url, school_records_url, lattes_url, experience, profile, course_certificates_url, course, registration, summary
```

I did some searching on the internet and thought I should set all the tables, but it didn't work. I did it this way:

```
def update(self, user_id: str, data: schemas.UpdateUser):
    user = self.db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.id == user_id)
    if not user:
        return 'User not found'
    resume = self.db.query(models.Resume).filter(models.Resume.user_id == user_id)

    resume_data = dict({
        'summary': data.summary,
        'experience': data.experience,
        'skills': data.skills,
        'course': data.course,
        'registration': data.registration,
        'school_records_url': data.school_records_url,
        'profile': data.profile,
        'github_url': data.github_url,
        'lattes_url': data.lattes_url,
        'course_certificates_url': data.course_certificates_url
    })

    db_user = user.first()
    db_resume = resume.first()

    updated_data = data.dict(exclude_unset=False)

    user.filter(models.User.id == user_id).update(updated_data, synchronize_session=False)
    resume.filter(models.Resume.user_id == user_id).update(
        {
            "summary": resume_data['summary'],
            "experience": resume_data['experience'],
            "skills": resume_data['skills'],
            "course": resume_data["course"],
            'registration': resume_data['registration'],
            "school_records_url": resume_data['school_records_url'],
            "profile": resume_data['profile'], "github_url": resume_data['github_url'],
            "lattes_url": resume_data['lattes_url'],
            "course_certificates_url": resume_data['course_certificates_url']}
        , synchronize_session=False)
    self.db.commit()
    self.db.refresh(db_user)
    self.db.refresh(db_resume)
    return {"status": "success"}
```

Comment: The error message means that the listed unconsumed columns don't exist on the table that you are trying to update. Check that these columns actually exist on the table in the database.

Comment: check database column are exists or not, if not then use alembic to migrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it this way:

```
def update(self, user_id: str, data: schemas.UpdateUser):
    user = self.db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.id == user_id).first()
    if not user:
        return 'User not found'

    resume = self.db.query(models.Resume).filter(models.Resume.user_id == user_id).first()
    if not resume:
        return 'Resume not found'

    user.name = data.name
    user.email = data.email

    resume.summary = data.summary
    resume.experience = data.experience
    resume.skills = data.skills
    resume.course = data.course
    resume.registration = data.registration
    resume.school_records_url = data.school_records_url
    resume.profile = data.profile
    resume.github_url = data.github_url
    resume.lattes_url = data.lattes_url
    resume.course_certificates_url = data.course_certificates_url

    self.db.commit()

    return {"status": "success"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong syntax in the `.update()` call.

Or, at least, you're doing it a different way than I'm used to.

This is how I do it:

```
resume.filter(Resume.user_id == user_id).update({
    Resume.summary: resume_data['summary'],
    Resume.experience: resume_data['experience'],
    ...
})
```

The dictionary keys should be actual model fields, like `Resume.summary`, not plain strings like `"summary"`.

Comment: I updated it to be as you mentioned, it stayed that way. But I had the same error ;(                 

```python
models.Resume.summary: resume_data['summary'],
models.Resume.experience: resume_data['experience'],
```